# Is there any difference between Rc::clone(&rc) and rc.clone() in Rust? Is there any compilation optimizations happen based on that?

Tags: rust

I noticed the rust book [recommends](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-04-rc.html#using-rct-to-share-data) to use `Rc::clone(&rc)` over `rc.clone()` as follows:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

let five = Rc::new(5);

// recommended
let _ = Rc::clone(&five);

// not recommended
let _ = five.clone();
```

Why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The function syntax (`Rc::clone(&rc)`) makes it clear you're only making a new shared reference (cheap), rather than cloning the underlying object being referenced (maybe expensive). For arbitrary reference counted types, it may not be clear if a shallow or deep copy is occurring.

This issue with readability/clarity has led to [proposals for a separate interface for cloning reference counted pointer types](https://github.com/nical/rfcs/blob/rc-newref-clone/text/0000-rc-newref-clone.md#example), with [linters now warning when a reference counted type is cloned via a method](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/1645).