# Why does cloning an Rc pointer in Rust increase its strong_count?

Tags: pointers, rust, clone, ownership, reference-counting

I have this function:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

fn rc_counter() -> Rc<String> {
    let p1 = Rc::new(String::from("Hello"));
    println!("count {}", Rc::strong_count(&p1)); // 1
                                                 // this is an owned type not a reference
    let p2 = p1.clone();
    println!(
        "Count after the clone is created for the pointer {}",
        Rc::strong_count(&p1)
    ); // 2
    p2
}
```

1. I created `p1` pointer. Print its strong count as 1
2. then I cloned it and checked the strong count of "p1" and it prints out 2.

As far as I know, cloning means, replicating the pointer in stack and replicating the data in the heap. But looks like cloned `p2` is still related to the `p1`. How is this possible?

Comment: Have you read the [`Rc` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/index.html)? Quote from the page: "Invoking clone on Rc produces a new pointer to the same allocation in the heap."

Comment: Related: [Is there any difference between Rc::clone(&rc) and rc.clone() in Rust? Is there any compilation optimizations happen based on that?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61949769/364696) (The answer: One of them has an obvious meaning, the other still does the same thing, but is confusing, creating confusion of the sort you, Yilmaz, are experiencing)

Answer (score 3):

That's the whole point of `Rc` - `Rc` is a **reference counting smart pointer** for **shared ownership**. It makes it possible that multiple owners own it simultaneously.

To not break Rust's ownership rules, all of the owners can only access it **immutably**, though.

For that reason, `.clone()` is kind of discouraged, because it doesn't make it clearly readable whether it clones the `Rc` or the inner object.

In your case, `p1.clone()` is equivalent to `Rc::clone(&p1)`.

If you want to clone the inner `String`, you need to do `String::clone(&p1)`, or `(*p1).clone()`.

---

> As far as I know, cloning means, replicating the pointer in stack and replicating the data in the heap. But looks like cloned `p2` is still related to the `p1`.

You are describing the behavior of `Box`. If you want non-shared ownership of an object on the heap, and if you clone it it also clones the object on the heap, use `Box` instead of `Rc`. The two are very similar apart of the fact that `Rc` is for shared ownership.

Comment: "You are describing the behavior of Box." - More like the behavior of any owned clonet

Comment: @Caesar Your point?

Comment: Woops, my comment got cut short. I wanted to make a point about how Rust somehow has both deep copy (for owned struct members and boxes and whatnot) and shallow copy (for referenced values and Rcs) in the same clone trait. If you've used a language before that makes a distinction between these two, Rust can feel weird, and occasionally, it can be difficult to know what a clone followed by modifications does without consulting documentation. I think it deserves a bit more explanation than just "that's the behavior of `Box`", but I'm not sure what kind.

Comment: @Caesar My intention was to point him in the right direction so he can read the appropriate documentation. There's enough documentation about this topic already, like in the Rust book, so I don't think I should go into lengths here.